# Sending File data from Vue frontend to Flask backend: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python, json, vue.js, flask, server

My goal is to have a user fill out a form where they upload a file and give it a custom name, and that data is sent to my backend Flask server. I specifically want the file itself so I can open it and read it in the backend.

I was having issues receiving the file data, so I decided to use the FormData interface.

In SubmitJob.vue:

```
            const formData = new FormData(); // Create FormData object
            formData.append('file', file.value as File);
            formData.append('name', name.value as string);
            formData.append('printerid', selectedPrinter.value?.id?.toString() || '');
            await addJobToQueue(formData)
```

Then in jobs.ts:

```
export function useAddJobToQueue(){
    return {
        async addJobToQueue(job: FormData){
            try{
                const response = await api('addjobtoqueue', job);
                return response; 
            }catch(error){
                console.error(error)
                toast.error("An error occurred while creating the job");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the backend route:

```
@jobs_bp.route('/addjobtoqueue', methods=["POST"])
def add_job_to_queue():
        file = request.files['file']  # Access file directly from request.files
        name = request.form['name']  # Access other form fields from request.form
        printerid = request.form['printerid']
        print(name)
```

I was getting the error:

```
Unexpected error: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

So, in my rest function, I added a check to send the headers as multipart form data:

```
export function rest(url: string, body?: unknown, method?: string, headers?: HeadersInit){
    console.log(body instanceof FormData)
    const contentType = body instanceof FormData ? 'multipart/form-data' : 'application/json';
    console.log(contentType)
    return fetch(url, {
        method: method ?? (body ? "POST" : "GET"),
        headers: {
            // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': contentType,
            ...headers
        },
        body: body ? JSON.stringify(body) : undefined
    })
        .then(response => response.ok 
            ? response.json()
            : response.json().then(err => Promise.reject(err))    )
}
```

The console.log statement evaluates to true. However, when I inspect the network headers after submitting the job and making the call to the backend, the headers still say application/json.

I don't even know if this is the right way to go about it in the first place, but I'm still getting the same error. If anyone could shed some light on this it would be greatly appreciated, hahaha!